# Is there an identity for $\arctan(x+y)$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Ive tried looking on the internet and I can't seem to find any identities for $\arctan(x+y)$. I was wondering if anyone knows any?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of identity do you expect, and why?

Comment: Id like to know how large is $\arctan(\pi/2-1/n)$

Comment: That's a very strange expression to be interested in... Are you sure you don't want $\tan(\pi/2-1/n)$? Or $\pi/2 - \arctan(1/n)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\arctan(x+y) + \arctan(x-y) = \arctan\left(\frac{2 x}{1-x^2+y^2}\right) \tag 1 $$

is valid because take tan on both sides using

$$ \tan( x+y)=\frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1- \tan x \tan y} $$

(1) holds. Similarly

$$\arctan(x+y) - \arctan(x-y) = \arctan\left(\frac{2 y}{1+x^2-y^2}\right) \tag 2 $$

Taking sum

$$2 \arctan(x+y)  = \arctan\left(\frac{2 x}{1-x^2+y^2}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{2 y}{1+x^2-y^2}\right)$$

If $z= x+iy  , u = $ real part of $ z^2 $

$$ 2 \arctan(x+y)  = \arctan\left(\frac{2 x}{1-u}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{2 y}{1+u}\right)$$

for whatever use it could be put to..

Comment: Just curious how you derived this identity. Especially the first two equations. Maybe if you could give me some more details, I'd much appreciate that!

Comment: It derives from  the identity starting first step $$ \tan( x+y)=\frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1- \tan x \tan y}$$

Answer (score 2):

The closest I know of is $$\arctan(x) + \arctan(y) = \arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$$

(of course up to a multiple of $\pi$, and for $xy \neq 1$)
Other than that I'm not aware of any useful ones.

Depending on what you want to achieve it might also be worth looking into [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions):